# Masonry with ajax tabs

Tags: ajax, wordpress, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to use masonry with ajax tabs but unfortunately it shows large gaps. Here is my code

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: ajaxurl,
data: {
    action:'activity_load',
    'tab_activity_type_object': tab_activity_type_object
},
success:function(data) {
    $( ".tab-content .tab-content-list" ).empty();
    $( ".tab-content .tab-content-list" ).append(data);
},
error: function(errorThrown){
    $( ".tab-content .tab-content-list" ).append( "Data error" );
    console.log(errorThrown);
}
});


jQuery(function(){
var $container = jQuery('.tab-content-list');
$container.masonry({
  itemSelector: 'li.activity-item'
});
});
```

I found some solution here -> https://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html
But I'm not sure how to use it code above.

Comment: I've ran into this issue in the past, and used custom CSS to optimize the white-space gaps.  The idea is that masonry uses CSS under the hood to do the same thing.  However as long as your CSS isolator is more declarative than masonry's it'll over-ride masonry's CSS with your own. Adjusting the margin prop should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was simpler than I thought

```
 $( ".tab-content .tab-content-list" ).append(data).masonry( 'reload' );
```